# how to make 1 condition for 3 arrays in 1 function?

Tags: php, arrays, multiple-conditions

The function works like this but I want to get one condition instead of the 3 so
the problem is how to make these 3 conditions into 1 condition for the same 3 arrays: "Name", "Nachname" & "Ort" in a function?

thank you for your help!

```
function check($felder = array()) {

$de = "<h2>Deine Eingaben:</h2>";
$probleme = array();


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


if (empty($felder["name"])) {
 $probleme['name2'] = 'n/a';
 $probleme['name'] = "Name ist auskunftspflichtig";
} else {
 $probleme['name2'] = test_input($felder["name"]);
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$probleme['name2'])) {
   $probleme['name'] .= "Nur buchstaben und Leerzeichen sind erlaubt";
 }
}

if (empty($felder["nachname"])) {
 $probleme['nachname2'] = 'n/a';
 $probleme['nachname'] = "Nachname ist auskunftspflichtig";
} else {
 $probleme['nachname2'] = test_input($felder["nachname"]);
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$probleme['nachname2'])) {
   $probleme['nachname'] .= "Nur buchstaben und Leerzeichen sind erlaubt";
 }
}

if (empty($felder["ort"])) {
 $probleme['ort2'] = 'n/a';
 $probleme['ort'] = "Ort ist auskunftspflichtig";
} else {
 $probleme['ort2'] = test_input($felder["ort"]);
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$probleme['ort2'])) {
   $probleme['ort'] .= "Nur buchstaben und Leerzeichen sind erlaubt";
 }
}

}
return $probleme;
}
```

Comment: Just iterate over `['name', 'nachname', 'ort']` and make all conditions dependent on that.

Comment: What does your current function look like, or rather what would it look like? Please show us your actual problem creating this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it?

```
<?php

function check($felder = NULL)
{
    if ($felder === NULL) {
        $felder = array();
    }

    $de = '<h2>Deine Eingaben:</h2>';
    $probleme = array();

    // Keys in array:
    $keynames = array('name', 'nachname', 'ort');


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        // For each keys:
        foreach ($keynames as $keyname) {

            if (empty($felder[$keyname])) {

                $probleme[$keyname.'2'] = 'n/a';
                $probleme[$keyname] = ucfirst($keyname).' ist auskunftspflichtig';

            } else {
                $probleme[$keyname.'2'] = test_input($felder[$keyname]);
                if ( ! preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/', $probleme[$keyname.'2'])) {
                    $probleme[$keyname] .= 'Nur buchstaben und Leerzeichen sind erlaubt';
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return $probleme;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
function check($felder = array()) {
  $de = "<h2>Deine Eingaben:</h2>";
  $probleme = array();
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($felder); $i++) {
      if (empty($felder[$i])) {
          $probleme[$felder[$i].'2'] = 'n/a';
          $probleme[$felder[$i]] = "Name ist auskunftspflichtig";
      } else {
        $probleme[$felder[$i].'2'] = test_input($felder[$i]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$probleme[$felder[$i].'2'])) {
          $probleme[$felder[$i]] .= "Nur buchstaben und Leerzeichen sind erlaubt";
        }
     }
    }
  }
return $probleme;
}
```